Is it acceptable to cite review papers when they don't provide any references for where the information has come from?
Is it acceptable to cite review papers when they don't provide references for where the information has come from?
I'm working on a report, and I've cited quite a few review papers, whose number I'm trying to minimise. Where possible I've found the original source for the information and cited it.
However, there is content which is the authors' own writing rather than a review, where they don't cite a source. I'm presuming this is where it's their own conclusions from their reviewing rather than a conclusion from a reviewed paper.
For example, in one source that highlights the advantages of post-combustion carbon capture compared to other technologies there is no citation for this. I've found other (non-review) papers reference this paper.
I'm being cautious, as it's generally bad practice to cite review papers.

Why is it generally bad practice to cite review papers? I see "See ref [x] and references therein" fairly often.

@Allure Depends on the field, but if you cite review papers, which are basically collections of parts of other works, the original work that  actually found the info you’re citing doesn’t get the attribution (and citation count) it should. In physics, my field, it’s expected good practice to go all the way down to the root of the citation tree, unless your info is the result of the review article itself (such as a summary statistics, a comparative analysis, or a record value). I would expect this to hold for the majority of fields.

When you say you're "presuming it's their own conclusions from their reviewing", is this not made clear in the paper? A well written review should have clear separation between the evidence they are reporting from the existing literature, and the conclusions drawn from that evidence.

In the example of the paper that highlights the advantages of post-combustion carbon capture, it should be clear what the source of the evidence for this claim is. I would expect them to have included multiple papers that show different advantages of this technology which are cited earlier in the paper, so that this claim can reasonably be stated as a synthesis of the included evidence.

I've noticed an increase in the number of really bad review papers lately. Long ago in ancient history, like maybe 15 years ago, at least in my field, most review papers fell into one of a few categories:

expert reviews by top names in a field summarizing their work and the work of others in their fields over a career of 15+ years
forward-thinking reviews that were really making an original case for a specific hypothesis, supported by previous literature but also really being intended to drive future work
very comprehensive, systematic reviews that filled some gap in the field and should probably be treated as original research except that the research data were from the literature rather than biological specimens

There were a few duds, but mostly these were excellent resources.
However, these days, I have encountered a couple new brands of reviews:

The student review, written by someone brand new to the field just working their way into it trying to have a publication in their first year.
The junk review. Maybe it's written by AI, maybe the author just typed it up over their lunch break, maybe it's the 5th almost identical review paper published by the same person over the past year or two.

These (4) and (5) seem to be pushed by the new trend towards open access publishing. Publishers are happy to take a fee for these papers that really serve no purpose except to pad someone's CV.
Anyways...reviews of the first three types are generally pretty authoritative. They contain not only statements regurgitating what is published, they also contain their own original thoughts in the synthesis of ideas. You absolutely need to cite them for that synthesis. You should also cite them when they've done the work for you of identifying useful sources.
I would be wary of the other two types, and if you're new to a field unfortunately you might have trouble identifying them. But, if you're finding a lot of statements of fact (rather than synthesis) that are unsupported, I think you've stumbled onto the "junk review".

A very important post

100%. I have noticed this too from more recently published review papers.

I sometimes call category 5 reviews “Google page reviews”, as they’re often barely more than the Google Scholar page you get after searching for “title of the review”.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't (3) be a meta-analysis rather than a review?

@BenVoigt I had in mind such papers that do not do any meta analysis and mostly synthesize data qualitatively. I also realize I used the phrase "systematic review" which is its own kind of research approach, which I didn't really mean to do, I meant to use systematic more broadly as an adjective to describe the depth.

I disagree that it is generally bad practice to cite review papers; see for example this answer. While it is good practice to track down, read, and cite the original source of a fact/idea (both to give credit and to avoid errors accumulating by the citation game of telephone), the broader perspectives of review articles can be very helpful to your readers, and provide an overview of more and more recent evidence than in the original source. Thus it often is appropriate to cite the review, or to cite both the original source and the review article.
In this case you mention original aspects in the review article. It is worth distinguishing two cases:

The review article includes statements of fact, with no source or evidence presented. If so, the review is likely a bad source for such claims, and it would be a good idea to look elsewhere.
The review article contains novel ideas/insights/interpretations/commentary synthesized from the primary research articles it cites. If it's done convincingly and carefully, this is a mark of a great review article—one that contributes more than an extensive list of references and some prose—well worth citing for such ideas.

Your example of "one source I have used highlights the advantages of post-combustion carbon capture compared to other technologies" doesn't really provide enough context to tell, but it might fall under the second category if it analyzes a variety of technologies and then arrives at this conclusion. But note the qualifiers "convincingly and carefully" and beware of confirmation bias and motivated reasoning. Especially for complex and policy-relevant claims like this it is good practice to be critical of the arguments presented, and to look also for evidence and arguments against the claim.

If you use something from a paper then you cite that paper. If that paper is flawed then you either cite it or avoid using it.
Not citing it when you use it will be the same error that is exhibited by the paper you use but don't cite.
But beyond the immediate question of citation, there is the issue of whether you should use such a paper at all. It seems flawed as you describe it, possibly even plagiarism in the worst case. In that situation you shouldn't touch it at all.

The issue of whether to cite a review paper versus a normal paper is a red herring here. What is bad practice is not citing a review paper, but citing a paper containing suspect information (whether it is a review paper or not) without alerting the reader to the issue.
If a paper makes a claim and doesn't cite a source for the claim or otherwise provide supporting evidence/reasoning, then if you repeat the claim in your paper, you have a duty to:

Cite the source where the claim came from.

Alert the reader to the fact that the claim is not substantiated in the source.


To be clear, you don't need to outright state that you believe the claim to be false. The readers can judge that for themselves. But you need to convey to the reader that you are not endorsing the claim and that they need to be aware of the lack of clear sourcing or reasoning. This can be done by writing something like:

Scienceman et al (2014) discuss the benefits of osteopathic healing techniques in the treatment of cats and other household pets, and claim that such techniques can extend the expected life span of the average household pet by 27 years. No source is given for a peer-reviewed study supporting the claim.

Even if you believe the claim you are mentioning is probably true, it is prudent to point out the lack of clear sourcing. Propagating facts which are possibly true but unverifiable is only slightly less bad than propagating outright falsehoods, particularly in the context of scientific research.
Of course, another option is simply not to mention the claim at all, in which case you also do not need to cite the paper where it is mentioned.

This. A citation should be more than only giving the bibliographic details of a paper. The text around it is important. It can be used to write something almost like a mini-mini critical review like in the given example.

The last sentence rings all the alarm bells: Look for a different paper! If you cannot find any backing the claim, it is probably not scientifically proven.
